# i send 3 or 4 digits but the server got and display only two digits of them in Qt socket

Tags: qt, sockets

I have a client and server. the server sends for example 9999 and client only show two digits of them like "99" and "99" or client send 1234 and server display "12" and "34" instead 1234. what's the problem?

server.h

```
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

class Server: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:

   QString buf;
  Server(QObject * parent = 0);
  ~Server();
public slots:
  void acceptConnection();
  void startRead();
  QString getinfo();

private:
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  QTcpServer server;
  QTcpSocket* client;
};
```

server.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "server.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "test.h"
#include "test2.h"
#include <QDeclarativeComponent>
#include <qquickview.h>

Server::Server(QObject* parent): QObject(parent)
{


  connect(&server, SIGNAL(newConnection()),
    this, SLOT(acceptConnection()));


  server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 8888);
  qDebug() <<  "connected";
}

Server::~Server()
{
  server.close();
}

void Server::acceptConnection()
{
  client = server.nextPendingConnection();
  client->write("Hello client\r\n");

  connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
    this, SLOT(startRead()));
}

void Server::startRead()
{

   client->waitForReadyRead(3000);
   QString buf=  client->readAll();
   qDebug() << buf;

   }


 QString Server::getinfo()
    {

     qDebug()<< buf;
        return buf;

    }
```

Application output

```
Starting C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0_1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-NHAJA-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\NHAJA.exe...
connected
accept connection
"12"
"34"
"99"
"99"
```

as you can see in the application output it show "12" and "34" instead 1234 that had send by client.
i really appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you send the information? Who is your client?

Comment: i use cmd and telnet program to connect and send information to server.

Comment: I've tried it and it works correctly, I think you're using your telnet client incorrectly. I also do not understand why you use the following function: `waitForReadyRead()`

Comment: when i don't use waitForReadyRead() method the server only display 1 digit  for example if client send "1234" the server display "1" "2" "3" "4" in 4 line respectively. i also shuld added that i use "CMD" and in the cmd i type "telnet 127.0.0.1 8888" and press enter and after i connected the server show me "hello client" and i type "1234" but i got "12" and "34" . is there any wrong with me?

Comment: Check that you are sending with wireshark, telnet sends a data every time you press enter. I have tried it with short messages and with very long messages and there is no delay necessary to use waitForReadyRead() since they are few bytes. I recommend deactivating your firewall.

Comment: thanks  @eyllanesc i disable firewall and i have the same problem.

Comment: I think it's a particular problem, try other computers and with other clients. :P

Comment: thanks again dear @eyllanesc

Comment: @alidaei, TCP doesn't guarantee that the bytes will come together. There are millions of similar questions on StackOverflow about the fragmentation of data.

Comment: can you post how to read & write information in your QByteArray ?

Comment: try to use QDataStream and QByteArray.

Comment: If we were to exchange large information, we could think that we could not read all the Byte (Partly comes). But 1234 ?! not...